# Find closest coordinates through a loop (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop, distance

```
x = {'d': (4, 2), 'b': (4, 4), 'c':  (2, 2), 'a': (4, 0)}
```

How do I get a list of keys from the dictionary that is sorted based on the closest distance from one coordinate to the next, using the Euclidean distance and assuming the list starts from `d`?

The list should look something like: `['d', 'a', 'c', 'b']`

The reason is coordinate `a` has the shortest distance to coordinate `d`, coordinate `a` will then be the second reference points to compare with the remaining coordinates in the dictionary that includes coordinates `c` and `b`. coordinate `c` is then the found out to be the closest coordinate to coordinate `a`. This process is continued until there are no more reference points in the dictionary.

Comment: *"closest distance from one coordinate to the next"* - Based on what? I don't understand your resulting list. I assumed you wanted sorted based on the distances of  `d` to `b`, `b` to `c` and `c` to `a` but that original list is sorted correctly in that way. The distance from `d` to the the nodes `b`, `c`, and `a` does also not give that result.

Comment: Also tag what language you are using, otherwise you will get answers on the logical steps you would need to do.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek apologies, I have edited my question. please look through it

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is a constant. Pass in a path ['d'] and remaining set(['a', 'b', 'c']) to your `find_closest` function. It looks at distance between `path[-1]` and each point in the remaining set, moving the winner from the set to the end of the list. Loop until the set is empty.

Comment: This is my intention, but i am having difficulty writing the loop

Answer (score 0):

> coordinate a has the shortest distance to coordinate d,

No, looking at your example coordinates, a, b & c are equidistant from d, i.e. 2, so there are multiple valid solutions:

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(p):
    p1, p2 = points[p]
    q1, q2 = points[path[-1]]

    return sqrt((q1 - p1) ** 2 + (q2 - p2) ** 2)

points = {'d': (4, 2), 'b': (4, 4), 'c':  (2, 2), 'a': (4, 0)}

path = ['d']  #  assuming the list starts from d

while len(path) < len(points):
    path.append(sorted([point for point in points if point not in path], key=distance)[0])

print(path)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>
```